# var x, y = 'foo'; Can this be accomplished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, syntax

Since it is possible to do:

```
var x = 'foo', y = 'foo';
```

Would this also be possible?

```
var x, y = 'foo';
```

I tried it, however x becomes undefined.

I know this may seem like a silly or redundant question, but if I'm curious about something, why not ask? Also you will probably wonder why I would need two variables equal to the same thing *in scope*. That is not the point of the question. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need two separate statements to get the exact same semantics.

```
var x, y; x = y = 'foo';
// or
var x = 'foo'; var y = x;
// or
var y; var x = y = 'foo';
```

The solution other users are suggesting is *not* equivalent as it does not apply the `var` to `y`. If there is a global variable `y` then it will be overwritten.

```
// Overwrites global y
var x = y = 'foo';
```

It is a good practice to correctly apply `var` to local variables and not omit it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: +1 You mention a very good point that other answers have completely neglected.

Comment: This is incorrect.  See my answer with jsfiddle which does it in one line.  I think my test proves that it can be done and also shows how pollution occurs with other types of statements.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, but your solution is exactly the same as the OP pointed out (`var x = 'foo', y = 'foo';`). Here, he's declaring and assigning *both* variables in a single line.  The importing thing to note is that the `var` keyword will apply to all variables when they are comma separated, meaning that the variables will be in the same scope, but that each variable still needs to be assigned.  Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons

Comment: @RoccoC5 No, the assignment in my solution is: var x = 'foo', y = x;  This is quite different.  There are two assignments with one literal value used.  Let me know if i can make it any clearer.

Answer (score 25):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you mean "Can I assign two variables to the same literal in one line without typing the literal twice?" then the answer is yes:

```
var x = 10, y = x;
```

Comment: +1 Who down-voted this without a comment? This is actually a valid alternative that hasn't been mentioned yet. In this case, both `x` and `y` are still local vars.

Comment: +1 from me too, this is as close as you can get to what the OP wants.  A single statement that declares both variables and initializes them to the same value.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>You can do</strike>

```
var x = y = 'test'; // Edit: No, don't do this
```

**EDIT**

I just realized that this creates/overwrites `y` as a global variable, since `y` isn't immediately preceded by the `var` keyword. So basically, if it's in a function, you'd be saying "local variable `x` equals *global* variable y equals …". So you'll either pollute the global scope, or assign a new value to an existing global `y` variable. Not good.

Unfortunately, you can't do

```
var x = var y = 'test'; // Syntax error
```

So, instead, if you don't want to pollute the global scope (and you don't!), you can do

```
var x, y;
x = y = 'test';
```

Comment: Yes, but then `y` is a global variable.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of assignments, the `y` identifier is *not* being **declared** as a variable, for example, if you do that in the scope of a function and if `y` is not already declared up in the scope chain, it will leak and it will be defined as a property of the global object (`window.y`). This is because assignments are evaluated from right to left, e.g. `var x = (y = 'test');` the first expression evaluated in that statement is the assignment of `y`. Also, assignments made to undeclared identifiers are completely disallowed on ES5 Strict Mode, to avoid *unintentional globals*.

Comment: @RoccoC5: Yeah, I realized that before I saw your comment, and updated my answer

Comment: @CMS: See my comment to RoccoC5 above

Comment: Flambino, yeah, I started to write my ~600 char comment before even @RoccoC5 commented ;)

Comment: @CMS: Heh, yeah, happens to me too. And I was editing my answer while RoccoC5 was writing his comment. _It's a race!_ :)

Answer (score 5):

In order for that to work, you will either need to initialize them separately (like your first example) or you will need to set them in a separate statement.

```
// This causes bugs:
var x = y = 'test';
```

Watch:

```
var y = 3;
function doSomething(){ var x = y = 'test'; }
doSomething();
console.log( y ); // test !?
```

On the other hand:

```
// this does not
var x,y; x = y = 'test';
```

Watch:

```
var y = 3;
function doSomething(){ var x,y; x = y = 'test'; }
doSomething();
console.log( y ); // 3 -- all is right with the world.
```

Comment: Just curious, but why did this get a -1?

Answer (score 5):

Below is my test function.  The currently uncommented line in the pollute function does what you were looking for.  You can try it and the other options in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gyxXE/2/).

```
var originalXValue = 'ekis';
var originalYValue = 'igriega';
var x = 'ekis';
var y = 'igriega';

function pollute()
{
    // Uncomment one of the following lines to see any pollution.
    // x = 'ex'; y = 'why';      // both polluted
    // var x = 'ex'; y = 'why';  // y was polluted
    // var x = y = 'shared-ex';  // y was polluted  
    var x = 'oneline', y = x;      // No pollution
    // var x = 'ex', y = 'ex';   // No pollution

    document.write('Pollution function running with variables<br/>' +
                   'x: ' + x + '<br/>y: ' + y + '<br/><br/>');
}

pollute();

if (x !== originalXValue && y !== originalYValue)
{
    document.write('both polluted');
}
else if (x !== originalXValue)
{
    document.write('x was polluted');
}
else if (y !== originalYValue)
{
    document.write('y was polluted');
}
else
{
    document.write('No pollution');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that although

```
var x = y = 'test';
```

is legal javascript

In a strict context (such as this example):

```
function asdf() {
    'use strict';
    var x = y = 5;

    return x * y;
}
asdf();
```

You will get:

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable y
```

to have it work without error you'd need

```
var x, y;
x = y = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use var x, y = 'foo' when you want to explicitly initialize x to undefined and want to restrict the scope of x.

```
function foo() {
  var x, y = 'value';
  // ...
  x = 5;
  // ...
}
// Neither x nor y is visible here.
```

On the other hand, if you said:

```
function foo() {
  var y = 'value';
  // ...
  x = 5;
  // ...
}
// y is not visible here, but x is.
```

Hope this helps.

Source: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid being tricky. Since I only use *one variable per `var` (and one statement per line)* it's really easy to keep it simple:

```
var x = "hello"
var y = x
```

Nice, simple and no silly issues -- as discussed in the other answers and comments.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why nobody posted that yet, but you can do this

```
var x, y = (x = 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
var a = b = "abc";
```

because in that case, b will become a global variable.

You must be aware that declaring a variable without var makes it global. So, its good if you follow one by one

```
 var a = "abc";
 var b = a;
```