# Javascript best practices, why to use comma to chain function/variable declarations?

Tags: javascript

I've been developing a plugin for jQuery "jQueryLog" to allow for debugging of chain selectors and return values. If you want to check it out, you can do it [here](http://www.jquerylog.com)

This is already a second version. The first version was actually an edited jQuery and while doing it I had to read jQuery to understand how the internals worked. The question comes from there:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    },

    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$,

    // A central reference to the root jQuery(document)
    rootjQuery,

    // A simple way to check for HTML strings or ID strings
    // Prioritize #id over <tag> to avoid XSS via location.hash (#9521)
    quickExpr = /^(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)/,
    (...)
```

Is there any big reason for the using a chain of declarations + "comma" instead of just using:

```
function jQuery ( selector, context ) { ... }

var _jQuery = window.jQuery;
var _$ = window.$;
etc...
```

The only reason I see here is for the minifier to have less literals that can't be cut down. But are there any other reasons?

Comment: Read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons)

Comment: I don't know that using commas over 'var' has ever been declared an industry 'best practice'.  At best, this is a stylistic preference.  I'd be interested in reading any article you could provide that advocated this as a best-practice, though.

Comment: @Ronak why don't you just say it's a duplicate question?

Comment: @ajax81 I guess if you consider JSLinting to be a best practice, then any recommendation it makes would also be a best practice.

Comment: OK... This' duplicate question.

Comment: just read this, I've added this question to the dupes. so my initial guess was right. Thought it might have anything else to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a shorter way to keep all the variables in the function scope while making sure they aren't used before they're defined.

In *[JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) (Sept. 2010, O'Reilly)*, Stoyan Stefanov calls it the **single `var` pattern**:

> JavaScript enables you to have multiple var statements anywhere in a
>   function, and they all act as if the variables were declared at the
>   top of the function. This behavior is known as hoisting. ... You use
>   one var statement and declare multiple variables delimited by commas.
>   It's a good practice to also initialize the variable with an initial
>   value at the time you declare it. This can prevent logical errors (all
>   uninitialized and declared variables are initialized with the value
>   `undefined`) and also improve code readability.