# Please interpret this java script line of code

Tags: javascript

Can someone interpret this javascript line for me?

```
    mouseWheelEventName = $.browser.mozilla ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel',
```

Need to know what "?" does, and what 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel', is saying particularly the "," at the end of the line... why isn't it a ";"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **ternary operator**, used as a shorthand conditional statement:

it's the same as saying:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    mouseWheelEventName = 'DOMMouseScroll';
} else {
    mouseWheelEventName = 'mousewheel';
}
```

The first piece before the `=` is declaring a variable (mouseWheelEventName) dependent on the following condition.

The next piece between `=` the `?` is the condition (is `$.browser.mozilla` true?).

Immediately after the `?` is the `then` portion (if the condition is true, set the variable mouseWheelEventName to the string `DOMMouseScroll`).

After the `:` is the else (if the condition is NOT true, set the variable mouseWheelEventName to the string `mousewheel`).

**Further reading:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

As for why there is a comma at the end of it, we'd need to see a more complete code sample including what follows that to say for certain. If I had to guess, I would say the author of the code was chaining variable statements.  This answer may shed some light for you: [Javascript best practices, why to use comma to chain function/variable declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638221/javascript-best-practices-why-to-use-comma-to-chain-function-variable-declarati) (see chosen answer)