# Javascript statement ending with comma or semicolon when object definition

Tags: javascript

All, I am not familiar with the javascript OO, After I did some experiment with it ,I have some little confused questions about the object definition ,Please help to review my code and comments below.Thanks.

```
    GlobalUtility = function() {
            this.templeteCode = "123";

            this.Init();
//why can not put this code here,
//there is an error says GetOriginalSource is not a function . 
//This is not like the classical OO constructor which can call any methods in class.
            this.Init = function() {
                var source=this.GetOriginalSource();
                alert(source + " is ok.");
            },//I found I can end this statement by , or ; Is there any difference between them?

            this.GetOriginalSource=function(){
                return "abc";
            };
            //this.Init(); putting this code here is ok .

        };
```

Comment: I think that this question need to be moved to `codeReview` or `Programmers`.

Comment: Hi ,@Red , Where is the codeReview and Programmers .Could you please give me a link. Next time I will follow it .thanks.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1 , http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1 also check out the amazing stack sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must define a function before calling it.
2. Semicolons in javascript are optional. Basically, a semicolon is used to end the statement while comma is when you working with objects. You could try reading these article [JavaScript variable definition: Commas vs. Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons) and 
   [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

Javascript can be written in an oop way *see [defining javascript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) but i recommended to use [Base.js](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/), it will make your life easier.

You probably need this but it is not that fun to read :) [javascript patterns](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/)

Comment: If you are compressing your code, it is good to use semi-colon (;), hence the code could become something else, ex: var foo = 1var bar = 2;
Also, when compressing, avoid // for comments, since it will comment the rest of the line to

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
GlobalUtility = function () {
            Init();


            this.templeteCode = "123";
            this.Init = Init;       
            this.GetOriginalSource = GetOriginalSource;

            //function declaration
            function Init() {
                var source = GetOriginalSource();
                alert(source + " is ok.");
            }
            function GetOriginalSource() {
                return "abc";
            }
};
```

You're trying to call a function that is not yet defined on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`this.GetOriginalSource=function(){` adds the function to the object. It is not there before this line. But you try to call it before.