# setting single javascript variable with many commas and multiple different objects

Tags: javascript

[CODE DEMO:](http://tributary.io/inlet/44efba81d5f0d23df323)

See Line 34:

```
// Tree creation functions
function branch(b) {
    var end = endPt(b), daR, newB;
    ...
```

(where `endPt(b)`, `daR`, `newB` are variables defined in this function, but omitted for simplicity)

What is going on here?

Possible solution: I've read this assets `var end` equals each of these,

> In JavaScript you can use commas to group any number of expressions
>   into a single statement. This is basically an artifact of the for
>   statement, where multiple assignment expressions are often grouped
>   together in the header.

[from here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781624/2700718)

Does that explanation directly apply here?

Comment: Nope, you'd just be declaring empty variables `daR` and `newB`. `end` will only be equal to `endPt(b)`

Comment: No, that explanation does not apply here, it does not have anything to do with the [multiple `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) you are experiencing here. You should rather read the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, you can declare multiple variables inline by separating via comma, so we can break down your example:

```
function branch(b) {
    var end = endPt(b), //a new variable called "end" is created and assigned the result of endPt with "b" as the parameter
    daR, //an empty variable called "daR" is declared
    newB; //an empty variable called "newB" is declared
```

As @Phil points out, it's probably easier to separate this statement into:

```
var end = endPt(b);
var daR, newB;
```

Comment: A better example might be to show `var end = endPt(b); var daR; var newB;`

Comment: @Phil -- Yeah - the confusion stems from the first is being assigned a value, the second two aren't.

Comment: Wow.  Major fail on my part for not recognizing the syntax!! Over-thinking it for sure, thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> (where endPt(b), daR, newB are variables defined in this function, but omitted for simplicity)
>
> What is going on here?

You are seeing the *declaration* of the variables `end`, `daR` and `newB`. `end` also is initialized with the value `endPt(b)`. It is a [multiple `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) equivalent to

```
var end = endPt(b);
var daR;
var newB;
```

> Does that explanation directly apply here?

No, that explanation does not apply here, it does not have anything to do with the construct you have here. You should rather read the [other answers on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781406/1048572).

The "comma expression" explanation would apply to

```
var end = (endPt(b), daR, newB);
```

where it would evaluated `endPt(b)`, `daR`, and then assign the value of `newB` to `end`.