# Javascript Syntax: Variable Declarations

Tags: javascript, syntax, keyword

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and filled with questions, most of which I'm able to find the the answers to online. However, there is the rare occurrence when my wording of a question doesn't correctly communicate the idea I'm trying to portray. That's when I come to Stack Overflow, and try to communicate more visually.

[image: line break]
**Which of these two examples is more commonly acceptable when programming with Javascript?**

*Method 1:*

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
```

*Method 2:*

```
var one=1,
    two=2;
```

[image: line break]
**Are there more specific (organizational) occasions when *Method 2* should be used?**

*Example:*

```
// Food
var pizza,
    sushi,
    cheeseburger;

// Utensils
var fork,
    spoon,
    excalibur;
```

[image: line break]
Just in-case you believe the answer to this question is purely subjective, I pose a different question for you: **which way (in terms of storage) is more efficient, and is the size of the difference insignificant for larger-scale web apps?**

Comment: It is personal preference on style. There is really no difference in storage. File size difference is going to be how many extra vars you have.

Comment: It's just style, there should be no impact on the operation of the script.

Comment: Duplicate post to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual machine treats the two identically. There will be no performance difference between the two. Stylistically some developers prefer the former, while I have always used the latter. Ultimately whatever you find more readable and whatever is the communalized standard at your organization is the one to go with.