# what does mean for "var data = jQuery(msg), script;" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

this comes from google chrome extension codes

```
"search" == request.ajax && $.ajax({
        url: request.url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
      }).done(function(msg) {
        if (msg.indexOf("https://login.testabc.com/?from=sm&return_url=") > -1)
          return void chrome.tabs.query({
            index: tabs[0].index
          }, function(a) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(a[0].id, {
              type: "ezusy_searched",
              dataSearch: "login"
            }, function(a) {})
          });
        var data = jQuery(msg), script; //what is msg && script?
        data.each(function(a) {
          $(this).text().indexOf("window.runParams") > -1 && (script = $(this).text())
        }),
          eval(script); //what does it mean?
```

what are the script and msg? why code like this.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see a bit larger context to know the overall purpose of this code, but in general, this code is fetching some content from the page and if it finds `"window.runParams"` in that content, then it's assigning that content into the `script` variable with `script = $(this).text()` and then executing it as Javascript with `eval(script)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the link I have attached for more detail. I will extract some of the content here:

**(i) $.ajax().done()**

`$.ajax()` returns an `jqXHR` object.

Then according to the specification -  `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`, the `msg` variable in your code snippet refer to the `data` parameter.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax#jqXHR

**(ii) [JavaScript variable definition: Commas vs. Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons)**

The `script` variable is just a variable that you declared in your code

**(iii) eval()**

The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval