# What is happening when you're destructing an array without using square brackets?

Tags: javascript

Python developer here. I am using JavaScript to run the following command,

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b , c, d = a;
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

To my surprise, `b` and `c` are undefined while `d` is the entire `a` variable. I later realize that I am meant to go `let [b, c, d] = a;`, however I am just trying to understand what is happening and why they're undefined.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript variable definition: Commas vs. Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781406)

Comment: What did you mean by:  " I am meant to go let [b, c, d] = a;"  ??

Comment: @MikeB to correctly assign b to 1, c to 2 and d to 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *not* destructuring.

```
let b , c, d = a;
```

Declares 3 variables and assigns a value to one of them. The line above is identical to:

```
let b;
let c;
let d = a;
```

This syntax allows you to declare (and optionally assign) several variables in a single statement, e.g.

```
let tmp, x = 4, i, y = 2, z = x * 10 + y;
```

Unassigned variables are default-initialized to `undefined`.

Reference:

- [ECMAScript 2024: 14.3.1 Let and Const Declarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript,

```js
let b, c, d = a;
```

defines the variables b, c, and d. It also initializes d with the value of a, or the array [1, 2, 3] but leaves b and c uninitialized.

When you try to print the values of uninitialized variables to the console in Javascript, it prints `undefined` to signify the lack of any value.